# AWS SageMaker - All metrics in statistics.json by Model Quality Monitor are 0.0, but confusion matrix is built properly for multi class classification

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I have scheduled an hourly model-quality-monitoring job both the jobs, ground-truth-merge and model-quality-monitoring completes successfully without any errors. but, all the metrics calculated by the job are "0.0 +/- 0.0" while the confustion matrix gets calculated as expected.

**Logs**

Here's the `statistics.json` file that model-quality-monitor saved to S3 with confustion matrix built, but with 0s in all the metrics:

````js
```
{
  "version" : 0.0,
  "dataset" : {
"item_count" : 4432,
"start_time" : "2022-02-23T03:00:00Z",
"end_time" : "2022-02-23T04:00:00Z",
"evaluation_time" : "2022-02-23T04:13:20.193Z"
  },
  "multiclass_classification_metrics" : {
"confusion_matrix" : {
  "0" : {
    "0" : 709,
    "2" : 530,
    "1" : 247
  },
  "2" : {
    "0" : 718,
    "2" : 497,
    "1" : 265
  },
  "1" : {
    "0" : 700,
    "2" : 509,
    "1" : 257
  }
},
"accuracy" : {
  "value" : 0.0,
  "standard_deviation" : 0.0
},
"weighted_recall" : {
  "value" : 0.0,
  "standard_deviation" : 0.0
},
"weighted_precision" : {
  "value" : 0.0,
  "standard_deviation" : 0.0
},
"weighted_f0_5" : {
  "value" : 0.0,
  "standard_deviation" : 0.0
},
"weighted_f1" : {
  "value" : 0.0,
  "standard_deviation" : 0.0
},
"weighted_f2" : {
  "value" : 0.0,
  "standard_deviation" : 0.0
},
"accuracy_best_constant_classifier" : {
  "value" : 0.3352888086642599,
  "standard_deviation" : 0.003252410977346705
},
"weighted_recall_best_constant_classifier" : {
  "value" : 0.3352888086642599,
  "standard_deviation" : 0.003252410977346705
},
"weighted_precision_best_constant_classifier" : {
  "value" : 0.1124185852154987,
  "standard_deviation" : 0.0021869336610830254
},
"weighted_f0_5_best_constant_classifier" : {
  "value" : 0.12965524348784485,
  "standard_deviation" : 0.0024239410000317335
},
"weighted_f1_best_constant_classifier" : {
  "value" : 0.16838092925822584,
  "standard_deviation" : 0.0028615098045768348
},
"weighted_f2_best_constant_classifier" : {
  "value" : 0.24009212108475822,
  "standard_deviation" : 0.003326031863819311
}
  }
}
```
````

Here's how couple of lines of captured data looks like(*prettified for readability, but each line has no tab spaces as shown below*) :

````js
```
{
"captureData": {
    "endpointInput": {
        "observedContentType": "text/csv",
        "mode": "INPUT",
        "data": "0,1,628,210,30",
        "encoding": "CSV"
    },
    "endpointOutput": {
        "observedContentType": "application/json",
        "mode": "OUTPUT",
        "data": "{\"label\":\"Transfer\",\"prediction\":2,\"probabilities\":[0.228256680901919,0.0,0.7717433190980809]}\n",
        "encoding": "JSON"
    }
},
"eventMetadata": {
    "eventId": "a7cfba60-39ee-4796-bd85-343dcadef024",
    "inferenceId": "5875",
    "inferenceTime": "2022-02-23T04:12:51Z"
},
"eventVersion": "0"
}
{
"captureData": {
    "endpointInput": {
        "observedContentType": "text/csv",
        "mode": "INPUT",
        "data": "0,3,628,286,240",
        "encoding": "CSV"
    },
    "endpointOutput": {
        "observedContentType": "application/json",
        "mode": "OUTPUT",
        "data": "{\"label\":\"Adoption\",\"prediction\":0,\"probabilities\":[0.99,0.005,0.005]}\n",
        "encoding": "JSON"
    }
},
"eventMetadata": {
    "eventId": "7391ac1e-6d27-4f84-a9ad-9fbd6130498a",
    "inferenceId": "5876",
    "inferenceTime": "2022-02-23T04:12:51Z"
},
"eventVersion": "0"
}
```
````

Here's couple of lines from my ground-truths that I have uploaded to S3 look like(*prettified for readability, but each line has no tab spaces as shown below*):

````js
```
{
  "groundTruthData": {
"data": "0",
"encoding": "CSV"
  },
  "eventMetadata": {
"eventId": "1"
  },
  "eventVersion": "0"
}
{
  "groundTruthData": {
"data": "1",
"encoding": "CSV"
  },
  "eventMetadata": {
"eventId": "2"
  },
  "eventVersion": "0"
},
```
````

Here's couple of lines from the ground-truth-merged file look like(*prettified for readability, but each line has no tab spaces as shown below*). this file is created by the ground-truth-merge job, which is one of the two jobs that model-quality-monitoring schedule runs:

````js
```
{
  "eventVersion": "0",
  "groundTruthData": {
"data": "2",
"encoding": "CSV"
  },
  "captureData": {
"endpointInput": {
  "data": "1,2,1050,37,1095",
  "encoding": "CSV",
  "mode": "INPUT",
  "observedContentType": "text/csv"
},
"endpointOutput": {
  "data": "{\"label\":\"Return_to_owner\",\"prediction\":1,\"probabilities\":[0.14512373737373732,0.6597074314574313,0.1951688311688311]}\n",
  "encoding": "JSON",
  "mode": "OUTPUT",
  "observedContentType": "application/json"
}
  },
  "eventMetadata": {
"eventId": "c9e21f63-05f0-4dec-8f95-b8a1fa3483c1",
"inferenceId": "4432",
"inferenceTime": "2022-02-23T04:00:00Z"
  }
}
{
"eventVersion": "0",
"groundTruthData": {
    "data": "1",
    "encoding": "CSV"
},
"captureData": {
    "endpointInput": {
        "data": "0,2,628,5,90",
        "encoding": "CSV",
        "mode": "INPUT",
        "observedContentType": "text/csv"
    },
    "endpointOutput": {
        "data": "{\"label\":\"Adoption\",\"prediction\":0,\"probabilities\":[0.7029623691085284,0.0,0.29703763089147156]}\n",
        "encoding": "JSON",
        "mode": "OUTPUT",
        "observedContentType": "application/json"
    }
},
"eventMetadata": {
    "eventId": "5f1afc30-2ffd-42cf-8f4b-df97f1c86cb1",
    "inferenceId": "4433",
    "inferenceTime": "2022-02-23T04:00:01Z"
}
}
```
````

I have done everything as mentioned in [this notebook for model-quality-monitoring from sagemaker-examples](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker_model_monitor/model_quality/model_quality_churn_sdk.ipynb) with very few changes and they are:

1. I have changed the model from xgboost churn to model trained on my data.
2. my input to the endpoint was csv like in the example-notebook, but output was json.
3. I have changed the problem-type from BinaryClassfication to MulticlassClassification wherever necessary.

Since, the confusion matrix was constructed properly, I presume that I fed the data to sagemaker-model-monitor the right-way. But, why are all the metrics 0.0, while confustion-matrix looks as expected?

Comment: Looks like you are checking all the right boxes. We might need to look at the logs behind the Model Monitoring job itself for more details. Could you please open a support case with endpoint ARN and processing job details?

Comment: i can sure provide the logs of the model monitoring job. i don't have that endpoint up anymore, it has been deleted; and i don't have a subscription to support plan to create a case for technical support and I can't afford subscription too. I am learning SageMaker by myself with resources available on internet.

Comment: please find the exported logs from cloudwatch here: https://controlc.com/1e1781d2

Comment: @RaghuRamesha, have you been able to gone through the logs? any insights?

Comment: Naveen, unfortunately, don't have an answer to it at the moment. I'll open a case internally to investigate this and keep you posted. Thank you.

Comment: Hey there! I am facing the same issue probably. Have you solved this? Might it be an issue that your model output is JSON and in the ground truth we have CSV? How should the model quality job compare those results? @RaghuRamesha is there support for JSON encoding in the ground truth yet?

Comment: i gave up. please write an answer if you find a fix.

Comment: I also gave up. We are using another provider for monitoring now.